# Node.js + SQL Server error : ConnectionError: Connection lost - read ECONNRESET

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I am using node-mssql Link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql
I am able to connect with SQL Server Management Studio.
while I am use node js to connect to SQL Server, I got the error messages, and trying to search for solutions.
But I can't find the right one.

This is my code.

```
const sql = require('mssql')
const config = {
    user: 'sx',
    password: 'XXXXXX',
    server: 'XXX.XXX.XX.XXX',
    database: 'XXXX',
    options: {
        "encrypt": true,
        "enableArithAbort": true
        },
    stream:true,
}
sql.connect(config).then(() => {
    return sql.query`select * FROM mydb.Department`
}).then(result => {

    console.dir(result)
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
    // ... error checks
})
sql.on('error', err => {
    console.log(1);
    // ... error handler
})
```

$ node index.js
// Error Details
ConnectionError: Connection lost - read ECONNRESET
at ConnectionError (D:\MakeP\node_modules\mssql\node_modules\tedious\lib\errors.js:13:12)
at Connection.socketError (D:\MakeP\node_modules\mssql\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1294:54)
at Socket. (D:\MakeP\node_modules\mssql\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1125:14)
at Socket.emit (events.js:326:22)
at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
code: 'ESOCKET'
}

`package.json` file
`Node js: 12.6.0`

```
{
  "name": "makep",
  "type": "commonjs",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "^3.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mssql": "^6.0.0",
    "net": "^1.0.2",
    "tedious": "^11.0.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you use `"encrypt": false` instead of `"encrypt": true`? If yes then you're probably connecting to an old version of SQL Server that doesn't support TLS 1.2.

Comment: Thank you @AlwaysLearning, I've try use both  `"encrypt": false` and `"encrypt": true`, but did't show different. Our SQL Server is 2000, It's really an old version..... Anyway, I appreciate your reply.

Comment: SQL Server 2000? Microsoft doesn't even support SQL Server 2008 R2 any more, you really should upgrade. SQL 2000 uses a quite old version of the TDS (Tabular Data Streams) protocol as well. You could try adding `"tdsVersion": "7_1"` to your config's options, but `mssql` may not even support that version any more.

Comment: I'll try adding  `"tdsVersion": "7_1"` and convincing my colleague to upgrade our SQL Server as well. Thanks a lot